# Why is my table not showing up at all using Angular 14 and having no errors?

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 14 and trying to create a table with 3 columns: DepartmentId, Department Name, and Options. I am filling this table with data from an SQLite database. No errors show up when running either `python3 manage.py runserver` or `ng serve`, but my table does not show at all, not even the table header. On localhost:4200, [my page looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmQk2.png) while it should look [similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ0lA.png).

I have checked my HTML for extra tags, and I made sure there are no undeclared inputs. Also, in `department.component.html` I have already added `<app-show-dep></app-show-dep>`

Here is the `app-routing.module.ts` file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { EmployeeComponent } from './employee/employee.component';
import { DepartmentComponent } from './department/department.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'employee', component: EmployeeComponent},
  { path: 'department', component: DepartmentComponent}
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is the `shared.service.ts` file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
readonly APIUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/";
readonly PhotoUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/";

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getDepList(): Observable<any[]>{
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.APIUrl + 'department/');
  }

  addDepartment(val:any){
    return this.http.post(this.APIUrl + 'department/', val);
  }

  updateDepartment(val:any){
    return this.http.put(this.APIUrl + 'department/', val);
  }

  deleteDepartment(val:any){
    return this.http.delete(this.APIUrl + 'department/' + val);
  }

  getEmpList(): Observable<any[]>{
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.APIUrl + 'employee/');
  }

  addEmployee(val:any){
    return this.http.post(this.APIUrl + 'employee/', val);
  }

  updateEmployee(val:any){
    return this.http.put(this.APIUrl + 'employee/', val);
  }

  deleteEmployee(val:any){
    return this.http.delete(this.APIUrl + 'employee/' + val);
  }

  UploadPhoto(val:any){
    return this.http.post(this.APIUrl + 'SaveFile', val);
  }

  getAllDepartmentNames():Observable<any[]>{
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.APIUrl + 'department/');
  }


}
```

Here is the `app.module.ts` file:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DepartmentComponent } from './department/department.component';
import { ShowDepComponent } from './department/show-dep/show-dep.component';
import { AddEditComponent } from './department/add-edit/add-edit.component';
import { EmployeeComponent } from './employee/employee.component';
import { ShowEmpComponent } from './employee/show-emp/show-emp.component';
import { AddEditEmpComponent } from './employee/add-edit-emp/add-edit-emp.component';
import { SharedService } from './shared.service';


import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DepartmentComponent,
    ShowDepComponent,
    AddEditComponent,
    EmployeeComponent,
    ShowEmpComponent,
    AddEditEmpComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the `show-dep.component.ts` file:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SharedService} from 'src/app/shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-show-dep',
  templateUrl: './show-dep.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show-dep.component.css']
})
export class ShowDepComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service:SharedService) { }

  DepartmentList:any=[];

  ModalTitle:string;
  ActivateAddEditComp:boolean=false;
  @Input() dep:any;




  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshDepList();
  }

  addClick(){
    this.dep={
      DepartmentId:0,
      DepartmentName:""
    }
    this.ModalTitle="Add Department";
    this.ActivateAddEditComp=true;
  }

  closeClick(){
    this.ActivateAddEditComp=false;
    this.refreshDepList();
  }

  refreshDepList(){
    this.service.getDepList().subscribe(data=>{
      this.DepartmentList=data;
    });
  }
  
}
```

Here is the `show-dep.component.html` file:

```
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>DepartmentId</th>
            <th>DepartmentName</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let dataItem of DepartmentList">
            <td>{{ dataItem.DepartmentId }}</td>
            <td>{{ dataItem.DepartmentName }}</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mr-1">
                    Edit
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mr-1">
                    Delete
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you rendering `<app-show-dep></app-show-dep>` in your `department.component.html` ? Or is it a child route?

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 I am rendering `<app-show-dep></app-show-dep>` in `department.component.html`.

Comment: Although I'm not getting data since I can't reach the server it is rendering the table headers for me in [this project on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mx7eca). Could you fork it and try to reproduce the issue to add it to your question pls? I'd love to help out, but seem to be missing some info.

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 It works perfectly on Stackblitz with all the data. Weird.

Comment: I was missing `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in `app.component.html` so it wasn't rendering anything.